Query Sql Warehouse in Databricks using ODBC in .Net
In an Asp.net application we need to query some data from Databricks. The Sql warehouse in Databricks provides an ODBC endpoint. The application we are developing will be hosted in Azure App Service, so no real access to the operating system to install any drivers.
The instructions I've found are either to install a driver on the server and define a DSN, or for a DSN-less ODBC connection is this:
string connectionString = "Driver={ODBC Driver Name};Server=YourServerAddress;Database=YourDatabaseName;UID=YourUsername;PWD=YourPassword;";
var connection = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

What should the "ODBC Driver Name" be? Databricks seems to have an own driver, but I don't think I can install that on an App Service and haven't found a nuget package or similar for it.

Possible duplicate.

I ended up using the Statement Execution API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/sql-execution-tutorial

We had the same problem. It is possible to install the ODBC driver in docker (so you need to dockerize the API first) and when in docker you specify the path to the driver (e.g. Driver=/opt/simba/spark/lib/64/libsparkodbc_sb64.so;Host=...)

Also, another point if speed matters for you - querying the data via the ODBC is twice as fast than the Statement Execution API.
